# Module system that works on Node.js and on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, module

You are programming a lib X that depends on lib Y. You want that library to work on node.js and on the browser. On node.js, you'd use `require('Y')`. On the browser, you could use require.js. What's the proper way to implement it so your lib is cross-platform?

Comment: You can use requirejs in Node (http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html). This lets you use a x-platform module loader.

Answer (score 4):

This one seems to be popular…

https://github.com/substack/node-browserify

Answer (score 2):

you can try https://github.com/component/component. it's similar to browserify